# Show results with solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, similarity

i'm using solr `http://lucene.apache.org/solr/`

I use a tutorial per index my collection and execute some simple queries via the graphical interface, avaiable at the address `http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/browse.`

But, now i would execute some queries via command line, so i use this:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/query -d '
q=*:*'
```

But, in doing so, i only obtain the sorted list of the documents, showing the entire contents of the documents, without the scoring result of each one.

So, how can i do to show only the title and the score of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `fl` query parameter which means field list. `score` for getting the score. e.g. `fl=title,score`. Assuming you are storing title as `title`.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/query -d 'q=*:*&fl=title,score'
```

For more information: [Common Query Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters)